# Grab all inserted or updated product ids from an inline sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two Store procedures,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProduct] 
(
    @ID  VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT,
    ..........................................
    ..........................................
    ..........................................


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProduct] 
(
    @ID  VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT,
    ..........................................
    ..........................................
    ..........................................
```

and I have a dynamic SQL which invoke these 2 sps,

```
Exec InsertProduct 
Exec UpdateProduct 
Exec UpdateProduct
Exec InsertProduct
Exec InsertProduct
Exec UpdateProduct
Exec InsertProduct
..........................................
..........................................
..........................................
..........................................
```

The problem is that I need to grab all the inserted and updated ids in the last of my dynamic inline sql in the same order. So, let say in my @Sqls varchar variable as a comma-seperated. Is this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your dynamic SQL

```
declare @ID varchar(10)

exec InsertProduct @ID = @ID output

select @Sqls = @Sqls + 'inserted ' + isnull(@ID, 'null')

exec UpdateProduct @ID = @ID output

select @Sqls = @Sqls + 'updated' + isnull(@ID, 'null')
...
```

and call your dynamic SQL like

```
exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = <your statement>,
    @params = N'@Sqls nvarchar(max) = null output',
    @Sqls = @Sqls output
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use magic tables

OUTPUT inserted and OUTPUT updated clause to your queries
    [Using OUTPUT after INSERT to get value of identity column into a (non-table value) variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221278/using-output-after-insert-to-get-value-of-identity-column-into-a-non-table-valu)